# python vowels counter in each word

Tags: python, python-3.x

how to check each letter in each word in a line if it has vowels

```
for line in inFile:
        wordlist=line.lower().split()
        count = 0
        for word in wordlist:
            if word[0] in vowels :
                word.count 
                continue
        outFile.write(str(count) + '\n')
```

Comment: for line in inFile:
        wordlist=line.lower().split()
        count = 0
        for word in wordlist:
            if word[0] in vowels :
                count+=1
                continue
        outFile.write(str(count) + '\n')

Comment: Do you want a total count of any vowels or a per vowel count?

Comment: i need to count each word sepertaly... 
(ana , john, joe) 
2 1 2

Comment: If the words apart multiple times do you want to see repeated counts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this as example, but it can be shorter and more pythonic:

Edited:

```
inFile = ('ana john joe', 'eric daniel veronica') 
vowels = 'aeiou'
counts = []
for line in inFile:
    count = 0
    words = line.split()
    for word in words:
        count = 0
        for character in word:
            if character in vowels:
                count+=1
        counts.append(str(count))
print(' '.join(counts))
```

Comment: it helped , but i need to count each word sepertaly...
(ana , john, joe)
2  1 2

Comment: the output might look like this
1 1 1 1 2
1 1 2 1 1
1 1 1 1 3
1 1 1 1 1 1

Comment: the first solution you had was kind of right , but let say if the first line has 4 words each word has two vowels , so the output should be  2 2 2 2 . i really appreciate your help , thanks alot

Comment: there's a problems
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: It works on my machine, "counts" is a list not an integer. I'm using Python 2.7.8

Comment: counts.append(str(count))
NameError: name 'counts' is not defined

Comment: okay it did work , but it has the double numbers , the code should be 6 numbers but the output is 12 , should i use (/2)??

Answer (score 0):

This gives a count for every word even if they appear multiple times, which you said you wanted:

```
for line in inFile:
    wordlist = line.lower().split()
    for word in wordlist:
        count = sum([1 for c in word if c in vowels])
        print("%s = %i" % (word, count))
```

Comment: i never took this way in class :(.. the first answer was right but it need to seperate each word so it has it own count of vowels

Comment: the output might look like this
1 1 1 1 2
1 1 2 1 1
1 1 1 1 3
1 1 1 1 1 1